# Excel - Replacing information in one field based on another field

Tags: excel

I have a list sorted by State and have 3 salespeople.   I need to replace the salesperson's name by their leads but don't want to have to do individually by state.   I saw one suggestion, but it would have to be done line-by-line or state-by-state.

Comment: This is one of those times where you have a picture in your head and feel that given your knowledge of the subject, have explained enough to get an understanding.  We do not have the sheet in front of us nor do we know your industry or its requirements.  Please attach some mocked up data and expected outcome.  It will help us get the needed background to better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot to go off of, if you can provide a sample of the data might be able to improve the solution.  Sounds like a vLookup or Index & Match

vLookup =VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE) - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Index & Match (=INDEX (column to return a value from, (MATCH (lookup value, column to lookup against, 0)) - https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/08/13/excel-index-match-function-vlookup/